# GSEA - Gene Set Enrichment Analysis - in R studio

Tags: r, rna-seq, gsea, java

I have been trying to conduct a classic GSEA using the broad institute software and can not figure out how to compile it in R for the life of me. I am aware that there exists other packages in R that are *almost* the same, such as `fgsea` however, I would like to use this one first and then compare it with these other methods.

I have already generated a ranked list for my contrast of interest and save it as a `.rnk` file. Here is what I tried to do:

```
gseaCallH <- 
  paste("java -Xmx2G -cp C:/Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/gsea2-2.2.4.jar xtools.gsea.GseaPreranked -param_file C:/Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/GSEAPrerankedParameters.txt -rnk C:/Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/gsea_treatFU_min.rnk -gmx C:/Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/h.all.v6.2.symbols.gmt -rpt_label gsea_treatFU_min.rnk -out C:/Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/C7",sep="")

testGSEA <- system(command = gseaCallH, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
```

When I run the `system` command I get the following error:
`had status 1`

At first I thought maybe it had something to do with JAVA not being properly installed however, I have installed it and still nothing. Maybe the installation was not done correctly? I have tried running it directly from cmd (I'm running windows 10) and got the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Can anyone advise on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you sure you have the specs to run the application? Did you check the Java version?

Comment: BTW, do you have the rJava package installed? It requires to configure R to be able to use Java (basically running `R CMD javareconf`) maybe it helps too. Because the way you run it now from R is sending it back to the command line, so you should get the error from the command line

Comment: If by specs you mean the software then yes, I have downloaded the desktop version of the application as well

Comment: Yes, then it might be a problem for their support system... Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I have answered my own question however, it is specific to windows users.. If you get the same error from the `cmd` as I did, you must manually put in environment variables related to Java. Do as the user Mohamed did in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for

Following this, you **must avoid** using paths such as `C:/absolute_path` and instead use `/absolute_path`, if you do the former, you will get the exception: `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c`

In the end, after manually entering the environment variables and running the following command: `java -Xmx2G -cp /Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/gsea2-2.2.4.jar xtools.gsea.GseaPreranked -param_file /Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/GSEAPrerankedParameters.txt -rnk /Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/gsea_treatFU_min.rnk -gmx /Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/h.all.v6.2.symbols.gmt -rpt_label gsea_treatFU_min.rnk -out /Users/omk/Desktop/BIOINFORMATIC/MsigDB/C7` it has worked.

Where the command can be executed directly from the command line or in R using the `system` function.

**Note**: A '#' separated by a *space* must be present at the beginning of your `.rnk` file for the program to work. Therefore, `.rnk` files must have the following format:

`# Genes  Coeffecients
TSPAN6    0.2345676` 
etc. for every gene.

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling java with sufficient memory? Try increasing `-Xmx2G` to `-Xmx8G`, provided your PC has 8 GB RAM.

Comment: Good call. I tried this and got the exception `Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx8G`

Comment: a quick google search suggests this might be due to 32 bit java vs 64 bit java?

Comment: So it actually had to do with the environment variables for Java in my computer. I had to manually insert some of them - _JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_HOME. Here is a SO post that was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303889/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for
Unfortunately I'm still getting an error - a different one though - malformed url exception, unknown protocol C. So I'm getting closer but still no luck..